# Intermittent file lock exception when calling File.AppendAllLines many times and file is open in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a number of methods on a class which I am calling via reflection:

```
var instances = new TestsBase[] {
    new CompilerGeneratedTestData(),
    new ConstructedTestData(),
    new VBCompilerGeneratedTestData()
};

var methods = instances
    .SelectMany(x =>
        x.GetType()
            .GetMethods()
            .Select(m => (instance: x, method: m))
    )
    .OrderBy(x => x.method.ReflectedType.Name)
    .ThenBy(x => x.method.Name)
    .ToList();
```

Each of these methods ultimately calls the following code:

```
string[] toWrite = ...
var outfileName = @"c:\path\to\text.txt";
File.AppendAllLines(outfileName, toWrite);
```

When I run the code, at some point I get the following exception at the call to `File.AppendAllLines`:

> **System.IO.IOException**: 'The process cannot access the file 'c:\path\to\text.txt' because it is being used by another process.'

The original method call appears to be different each time; it's not failing on a particular method.

The application is a simple console project, with no multithreading in my code.

**How can I avoid this error?**

---

I have a set of abstract classes with XUnit test methods:

```
public class ConstructedBase {
    protected abstract void RunTest(object o, string csharp, string vb, string factoryMethods);

    [Fact]
    public void ConstructAdd() => RunTest(Expression.Add(x, y), "x + y", "x + y", "Add(x, y)");

    ...
}
```

and a class which defines the implementation of `RunTest`:

```
class ConstructedTestData : ConstructedBase {
    protected override void RunTest(object o, string csharp, string vb, string factoryMethods) => Runner.WriteData(o, factoryMethods);
}
```

as forwarding to a `static` method:

```
public static class Runner {
    public static readonly string outfileName = @"c:\path\to\text.txt";
    public static void WriteData(object o, string testData) {
        string[] toWrite = ...
        File.AppendAllLines(outfileName, toWrite);
    }
}
```

---

**Update**

This error only appears to happen if the text file is simultaneously open in Visual Studio.

Comment: Which anti virus are you using?

Comment: @mjwills Avira.

Comment: @ZevSpitz *don't* call `File.AppendAllLines`. If you know you'll access the same file multiple times, create a `StreamWriter` and use that in your methods. Right now you'r paying the cost of opening/closing streams each time just to write a few lines.

Comment: @ZevSpitz if you want to use that code for logging, use a proper logging library. They've already solved the multithreaded writing problem without compromising performance.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Are you suggesting a performance benefit? Because this is not production code; it's only to produce test data. It seems to me much simpler to use `File.AppendAllLines` than to have to hold a `StreamWriter` and know when to close it.

Comment: If you're not using threads or tasks, and only using `File.AppendAllLines`, then you will not get that exception. Basically, there has to be something you're missing here. Either you're opening the file somewhere and don't properly close it, or you have tasks or threads involved.

Comment: Are other processes also doing the same thing? Or do you have just 1 process dealing with the file?

Comment: @ZevSpitz there's a huge performance *hit* right now and the resulting code is far more complicated than using a logging library or even a `StreamWriter`. Creating a `StreamWriter` is trivial and so is  closing it properly - just use a `using` block

Comment: If there's only one thread and only one instance of your program, then my guess would be the antivirus software, Disable it temporarily and you'll see if it has an effect.
Anitvirus software is much more attentive if the exe is not digitally signed.
So, if your code s going to be used in a productive environment, you should think about code signing.
Another solution would be a retry loop that tries to aooend the lines n times, assuming that no lines from a failed `AppendLines` were already written.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen There is only one process, and AFAICT there is only one thread.

Comment: What were the results after disabling the antivirus? https://blog.avira.com/exceptions-avira-antivirus-3-steps/

Comment: @mjwills Didn't seem to help.

Comment: @mjwills I'm not sure how much more minimal I can make this without losing relevant information. And as far as _reproducible_, it's an intermittent issue, and I sometimes cannot reproduce it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two alternatives:

1. Store all the output data in memory, and write it all in one shot using `File.WriteAllLines`.
2. If it is impractical to store everything in memory, it might be possible to write everything to a temporary file, then copy that file over to the destination.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is likely that Visual Studio (or anti virus) is holding a lock on the file.

You should close it in Visual Studio.